# jQuery Conditional statement inside ajax data

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can I make something like this for example?

```
$.ajax({
  url:'ajax.php',
  type:'POST',
  data: {
    id: 3,
    device: $("#ipole4").val(),
    name: $("#ipole5").val(),
    ip: $("#ipole6").val(),
    method: $("#ipole7").val(),
    if (2 == 2) {
      'info':2
    }
  },
})
```

I just want to send something more in the special case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this, but not with the syntax you have. You need to create the object first, then use the condition statement separately, like this:

```
var data = {
    'id': 3,
    'device': $("#ipole4").val(),
    'name': $("#ipole5").val(),
    'ip': $("#ipole6").val(),
    'method': $("#ipole7").val() 
};

if (2 == 2)
    data.info = 2;

$.ajax({
    url:'ajax.php',
    type:'POST',
    data: data
}
```