# How to know which data have to be send via ajax specific issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I'm learning JS and met another difficulty in my way, so hope anyone can help. No matter it will be solution in jQuery or Angular, anyway I need both and just wanna get the concept. So, I've got 2 types of tasks in my HTML, user may choose which one he gonna solve - audio or graphic. Now my JS looks like:

```
var request = $http({
  method:  'POST',
  url:     'check.php',
  data:    {
    'audioAnswer': $scope.audioValue.data,
    'imageAnswer': $scope.imageValue.data,
    'userAnswer':  $scope.userAnswer
  },
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
});
```

As you can see now I'm sending user answer and both questions ID (audio & graphic). So I don't know which one he has been solving and just compare both with user answer on my server, obviously it's not the best solution...

**EDIT**

Current HTML with audio & graphic tasks looks like

```
<div class="cptch_bottom-hold">
   <div class="cptch_player" id='cptch_blue-button' ng-show='show'>
     <i class="fa fa-volume-up cptch_icon-hold" id="cptch_icon">
       <audio ng-src='{{audioSrc.data}}' id="audioplayer"></audio>
       <input type="hidden" name="audio_answer" class="player_input" ng-model='audioValue'>
     </i>
   </div>
   <div class="image-hold" ng-show='!show'>
     <img class='cptch_image' ng-src='{{imageSrc.data}}' ng-if='imageSrc' alt='image'>
     <input type="hidden" name="image_answer" class="image_input" ng-model='imageValue'>
   </div>
</div>
```

So question is - how to understand which task user's been solving? Tasks changes just clicking on one button, so in one moment of time you can see just one task.
Any advises will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Choose your data *before* using it in the AJAX function. It is really pretty simple.

Comment: You need a way to distinguish what the user clicked on, and what was solved, so basically you're not asking us how to write a simple `if` condition, but how to know what your user did, without showing us any of that code at all ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Conditional statement inside ajax data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246816/jquery-conditional-statement-inside-ajax-data)

Comment: @adeneo got you, you are right. But I don't understand what actually I have to show to you guys to understand my problem...

Comment: @Jay Blanchard I'm sorry, my question was wrong and ambiguous. Edited now.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be:

You attach an event to both inputs, when someone starts typing, the other one disappears.
In the same event you can 'save' which one of both that is entered, so you can execute the if statement in your ajax call.

In the same event you should also check if the input is deleted, so you can show both inputs again.

Comment: Thx for your feedback, I'll try

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create the object outside the method, so not as argument of the method, like so:

```
 var data = {};
 if($scope.audioValue.data) { data.audioAnswer = $scope.audioValue.data);
 if($scope.userAnswer.data) { data.userAnswer= $scope.userAnswer.data);
 if($scope.imageAnswer.data) { data.imageAnswer= $scope.imageAnswer.data);

 var request = $http({
   method:  'POST',
   url:     'check.php',
   data:    data,
   headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
 });
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry, my question was about how to get what was solved. Edited. Anyway thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a data object to be sent before sending it.

Like this:

```
var dataToBeSent = {};

if (isAudioAnswer) {
    dataToBeSent.audioAnswer = $scope.audioValue.data;
    dataToBeSent.userAnswer = $scope.userAnswer;
} else if (isImageAnswer) {
    dataToBeSent.imageAnswer = $scope.imageValue.data;
    dataToBeSent.userAnswer = $scope.userAnswer;
}

var request = $http({
    method:  'POST',
    url:     'check.php',
    data:    dataToBeSent,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
});
```

Comment: Thank you too man and sorry, my question was about how to get what was solved. Edited. Anyway thx.